# How to handle an event that produces an image when a button is clicked

Tags: java, events, javafx

I am creating an interface that allows two users to play tic-tac-toe. The rules of the game do not need to be enforced, when the user clicks a button, either an "X" or an "O" needs to appear.

I already have the interface set up, but I am having trouble connecting the events that need to occur to the buttons.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {
    private GridPane gBox;
    private HBox hbox;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //int n = 18;

        //ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>(n);

        Image image = new Image("file:O.png");
        Image image2 = new Image("file:X.png");
    
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image2);  

        Button button1 = new Button("X");
        Button button2 = new Button("O");
        Button button3 = new Button("X");
        Button button4 = new Button("O");
        Button button5 = new Button("X");
        Button button6 = new Button("O");
        Button button7 = new Button("X");
        Button button8 = new Button("O");
        Button button9 = new Button("X");
        Button button10 = new Button("O");
        Button button11 = new Button("X");
        Button button12 = new Button("O");
        Button button13 = new Button("X");
        Button button14 = new Button("O");
        Button button15 = new Button("X");
        Button button16 = new Button("O");
        Button button17 = new Button("X");
        Button button18 = new Button("O");

        gBox = new GridPane();

        gBox.add(button1, 0,0);
        gBox.add(button2,0,1);
        gBox.add(button3,1,0);
        gBox.add(button4, 1,1);
        gBox.add(button5, 2,0);
        gBox.add(button6,2,1);

        gBox.add(button7, 0, 5);
        gBox.add(button8,0,6);
        gBox.add(button9, 1,5);
        gBox.add(button10,1,6);
        gBox.add(button11, 2,5);
        gBox.add(button12,2,6);

        gBox.add(button13,0,10);
        gBox.add(button14,0,11);
        gBox.add(button15,1,10);
        gBox.add(button16,1,11);
        gBox.add(button17,2,10);
        gBox.add(button18,2,11);

        gBox.setHgap(130);
        gBox.setVgap(10);
        gBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ButtonClickHandler mbh = new ButtonClickHandler();

        button1.setOnAction(mbh);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gBox, 380, 300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    class ButtonClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            Image image = new Image("file:O.png");
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            HBox hbox = new HBox(imageView);
 
            Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
            imageView.setImage(image);      
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're almost there. You just need to combine the `HBox` containing the `ImageView` and the `Button`. That and deal with the fact that you've got a 6 x 3 field instead of a 3 x 3 field and have chosen an approach to creating/adding the buttons that uses a lot of repetitive code. (Good luck writing 17 more lines like `button1.setOnAction(mbh)`; If I had to write code like this, it would only contain a single line like this...)

Comment: @fabian I know its alot of repetetive code, I figured you could put all of the buttons in an array or arraylist, anyway you can show me how that is done(or how you would do it) :)?

Comment: I don't really know what exactly you want to do. `btn.setGraphic(hbox);`? `Pane parent = (Pane)button.getParent(); GridPane.setRowIndex(hbox, GridPane.getRowIndex(btn)); GridPane.setColumnIndex(hbox, GridPane.getColumnIndex()); parent.getChildren().set(parent.getChildren().indexOf(btn), hbox);` ??? Something else? Depending on your requirements it could be useful to properly design a model and possibly design custom gui elements or at least creating/setting up the buttons in a dedicated method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproduces what you did, avoiding duplicate code while adding an event handler to each button:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {

    private static String[] BUTTONS_TEXT = {"X", "O"};
    private static int ROWS = 6, COLS = 3;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        GridPane gBox = new GridPane();
        ButtonClickHandler mbh = new ButtonClickHandler();

        for (int col = 0; col < COLS ; col++){
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS ; row++){
                Button button = new Button(BUTTONS_TEXT[0]);
                button.setOnAction(mbh);
                gBox.add(button, col, row);
            }
        }

        gBox.setHgap(10);  gBox.setVgap(10);
        gBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(gBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ButtonClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
            btn.setText(btn.getText().equals(BUTTONS_TEXT[0]) ? BUTTONS_TEXT[1] : BUTTONS_TEXT[0]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When you have the basic functionality working, you can take it to the next step and use button icons instead of text :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {

    private static int ROWS = 6, COLS = 3;
    private static String[] BUTTONS_TEXT = {"X", "O"};

    //always use publicly available resources when posting mre
    private static final String[] imageLink = {
            "http://iconsetc.com/icons-watermarks/simple-black/alphanum/alphanum_lowercase-letter-x/alphanum_lowercase-letter-x_simple-black_64x64.png",
            "http://iconsetc.com/icons-watermarks/simple-black/alphanum/alphanum_lowercase-letter-o/alphanum_lowercase-letter-o_simple-black_64x64.png",
    };

    //construct images once
    private static Image[] images=  {new Image(imageLink[0]), new Image(imageLink[1])};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        GridPane gBox = new GridPane();

        for (int col = 0; col < COLS ; col++){
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS ; row++){
                Button button = new Button();
                button.setOnAction(new ButtonClickHandler(BUTTONS_TEXT[0]));
                button.setGraphic(new ImageView(images[0]));
                gBox.add(button, col, row);
            }
        }

        gBox.setHgap(10);  gBox.setVgap(10);
        gBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(gBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ButtonClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        private String buttonState; //keeps the current state of the button

        ButtonClickHandler(String buttonState){
            this.buttonState = buttonState;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){

            Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
            if(buttonState.equals(BUTTONS_TEXT[0])){
                btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageLink[1]));
                buttonState = BUTTONS_TEXT[1];
            }else{
                btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageLink[0]));
                buttonState = BUTTONS_TEXT[0];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: thanks @C0der! Not exactly the specifications I needed regarding the events that were suppose to happen with a button click. But I can finish it up from there. Really appreciate you taking the time to show me the mre I was looking for. Will definitely have more questions in the future, you seem to have a pretty good handle on JavaFX.Right now im working on exactly how to ask the right questions on stackoverflow. Which will come in time.

Comment: _" But I can finish it up from there"_  that is the purpose of this site. The answers are meant to help you write your own code. I am glad it helps. When you post new questions, leave me a message (tagged with @c0der as you did here) and I'll try to help. I can help with Java, Swing and JavaFx questions.

Comment: cool, whats your background? Are you currently in the software development field?

Comment: If you open to it, id even possibly paying to for this mentorship. Def helps alot.

Comment: @DanSchmidt thanks for the kind offer. On this site we all try to help and share our limited knowledge voluntarily. I hope you benefit from it, and also share your knowledge with others.

Comment: ! awsome sounds good to me, definitely be in touch with more question. this was a very simple problem obviously but I am very excited to get more into larger software projects. *Im starting to learn more here from stack overflow contributors than I do in a classroom*

Comment: trying to get my interface to look like the image below, been using column constraints but they are not working for me, any imput?