# How to load images on stage with EventHandler<MouseEvent>?

Tags: java, javafx

I have this piece of code. I want to add images. Here I have cross board which is divided on nine rectangles. Here is a image [crossboard](https://pasteboard.co/JbGh70B.png)
|1|2|3|
|4|5|6|
|7|8|9|

I would like to load another image: X.png or O.png if I click on rectangle for example number 1 an image will be loaded. 
How to do this in JavaFx? Is it possible?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;

public class background extends Application {

private class Tile extends StackPane {
    private Text text = new Text();

    public Tile() {
        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(200, 200);
        border.setFill(null);
        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 95));

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().addAll(border, text);

    }

    private void drawX() {
        text.setText("X");
    }

    private void drawO() {
        text.setText("O");
    }

}

private Parent createContent() {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(600, 600);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            background.Tile tile = new background.Tile();
            tile.setTranslateX(j * 200);
            tile.setTranslateY(i * 200);

            root.getChildren().add(tile);

        }
    }
    return root;
}


// launch the application 
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    try {


        // set title for the stage
        stage.setTitle("creating Background");

        // create a label 
        Label label = new Label("Name : ");

        // create a text field 
        TextField textfield = new TextField();

        // set preferred column count 
        textfield.setPrefColumnCount(10);

        // create a button 
        Button button = new Button("OK");

        // add the label, text field and button
        HBox hbox = new HBox(label, textfield, button);

        // set spacing
    //    hbox.setSpacing(10);

        // set alignment for the HBox 
    ///    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // create a scene 
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 600, 600);

        // create a input stream 
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\fill.png");

        // create a image 
        Image image = new Image(input);

        // create a background image 
        BackgroundImage backgroundimage = new BackgroundImage(image,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

        // create Background 
        Background background = new Background(backgroundimage);

        // set background 
        hbox.setBackground(background);

        // set the scene 
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Main Method 
public static void main(String args[])
{

    // launch the application 
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://github.com/sedj601/TicTacToeFX_2

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58736192/3992939) may help

Comment: java naming conventions, please ..

Answer (score 0):

One cool thing you can do is to setup a `GridPane` object and use it in order to display the cross-board, then change the state of the inner object (a button too is okay, or a simple pane with a background) to display it as a circle or a cross. It's really what you need to realise it.

[image]

Inside, you can then put an object which will listen for a click and you will be able to emulate the tic-tac-toe game pretty easily.
You can use an internal variable to keep in memory the current state of the game.
Give it a shoot.